# How to set selected value in jquery select2 laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, select, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 in my laravel apps. I have a problem when update the data. There is a data in the database that I input before. But when I try to update, the data won't selected in my select2. There are data on the list of select2 like in the picture below:

[image]

I am using ajax too, so if I change the patient relationship data, the patient name is automatically change depends on the patient relationship. This is my function :

```
function medical_update_modal(ID, CLAIMDATE, EMPL_ID, PATIENTRELATIONSHIP, EMPLFAM_ID, EMPLFAM_NAME, CLAIM_TYPE, CLAIMAMOUNT, MEDICALPARTNER, CLAIMTYPE) {
    $('#medical_id_update').val(ID)
    $('#receipt_date_update').val(CLAIMDATE);
    $('#patient_relationship_update').val(PATIENTRELATIONSHIP);
    $('#claim_type_update').val(CLAIM_TYPE);
    $('#claim_amount_update').val(CLAIMAMOUNT);
    $('#partner_type_update').val(MEDICALPARTNER);
    $('#claim_type_update').val(CLAIMTYPE);
    $('.selectpicker').select2('destroy');
    $('.selectpicker').select2({
        theme: "bootstrap"
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: "getPatientName",
        type: "GET",
        data: "PATIENT_RELATIONSHIP="+PATIENTRELATIONSHIP,
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
          var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
          $("select#patient_name_update").html(obj.opt);
        }
    }); 
}
```

This is code in the controller:

```
public function getPatientName(Request $request)
{   
    $relation = $request['PATIENT_RELATIONSHIP'];
    if($relation == 'Own Self'){
        $getpatientrelation = DB::select("SELECT EMPL_ID AS EMPLFAM_ID, EMPL_NAME AS EMPLFAM_NAME FROM [HUMANCAPITAL].[dbo].[EMPLOYEE] WHERE EMPL_ID = '" . Session::get('Empl_ID') . "'");
    }
    else{
        $getpatientrelation = DB::select("SELECT EMPLFAM_ID, EMPLFAM_NAME, EMPLFAM_RELATIONSHIP FROM [HUMANCAPITAL].[dbo].[EMPLFAMILY]  WHERE EMPL_ID = '". Session::get('Empl_ID') ."' and EMPLFAM_GENDER = 'Female' and EMPLFAM_RELATIONSHIP = 'Spouse'");
    }

    $msg["opt"]="";
    $msg["opt"] .='<option></option>';
    foreach($getpatientrelation as $getData):
        $msg["opt"] .='<option value="'.$getData->EMPLFAM_ID.'"> '.$getData->EMPLFAM_NAME.'</option>';
    endforeach;
    echo json_encode($msg);

}
```

This is code in the view:

```
<select id="patient_name_update" name="patient_name_update" class="form-control selectpicker"  style="width:100%" required></select>
```

Do you know what I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You are using **select2** so don't get more confuse.

> On server side while loading/looping your options just add **selected="selected"** to those options you want to show automatically selected.

Then at end of your page add javascript

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('select').select2();
 });
</script>
```

> Select 2 will automatically show selected options that has **selected="selected"**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `.va()` method to set selected value like

```
success: function(data){
          var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
          $("select#patient_name_update").html(obj.opt);
          $("select#patient_name_update").val(selectedval);
        }
```